# How to connect to twitpic API with PHP?

Tags: php, twitter

I can't connect to the twitpic API. I've tried this:

```
$post = array (
    'key' => 'fghgfhdfghf',
    'consumer_token' => 'retert',
    'consumer_secret' => 'ertertwerwtetey',
    'oauth_token' => 'wety43y4y4wy',
    'oauth_secret' => 'seryeryereshrh',
    'message' => 'ffff',
    'media' => file_get_contents('http://img.yandex.net/i/www/logo.png')
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://api.twitpic.com/1/upload.json');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
echo $errno = curl_errno($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
echo $response;
```

What's wrong with this code? Can anyone give me an example of how to get this working?

Comment: Some sort of error would be handy.

Answer (score 2):

"file_get_contents" is not allways Enabled on a server

Answer (score 1):

PEAR has a package for that which abstracts you from the details: [Services_Twitter_Uploader](http://pear.php.net/pepr/pepr-proposal-show.php?id=650)

Answer (score 0):

You can't stream the image just like that. You have to download it first, for example, to a temporary file:

```
$tempname = tempnam( sys_get_temp_dir(), 'twitpic' );
file_put_contents( $tempname, file_get_contents( 'http://img.yandex.net/i/www/logo.png' ) );
```

The `media` field will be then set like this:

```
$post['media'] = "@$tempname";
```

After the requested is done (after `curl_exec()`), you can delete the temporary file:

```
unlink( $tempname );
```